# What, apart from gravy, can you make with chicken giblets?

Tags: chicken

I just smoked a whole pile of chickens for a Memorial Day BBQ, and have a whole tupperware full of giblets in the fridge. You can use giblets for broth, and for gravy. Is there some other way to use them? Perhaps as an entree?

Comment: Dang it King, its closed.  And I invented an awesome giblet rhubarb meatball recipe for you!  I want to make it now but not sure where I will find that many giblets.

Comment: @Willk And I threw out the giblets about an hour ago :(